# Jeffreys' prior for Bernoulli sampling

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, jeffreys-prior

I am learning Bayesian Statistics and I don't understand the Jeffreys' prior for Bernoulli sampling below:

[image]

If I understood well s is the number of observations when x=1 and f=n-s , where n is the number total of observations.

But what I misunderstood is that I wonder why Ex|θ(s)= nθ and Ex|θ(f)= n(1-θ).

Any clear explanation for this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\theta$, the expected value of all the x'es are just independent Bernoulli trials with success probability $\theta$, and subsequently the expectation is just $\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb E_{x_i|\theta}(x_i) = n\mathbb E_{x_i|\theta}(x_i) = n \theta$, since each $x_i$ is independent from all other $x_j$.

Your variable $f$ corresponds to the number of failures - by symmetry, the number of successes in $n$ Bernoulli trials with parameter $\theta$ is the same as the number of failures in $n$ Bernoulli trials with parameter $1-\theta$. Subsequently, the expected value of the failures is just $\mathbb E_{x_i|1-\theta}(x_i) = n(1-\theta)$.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are calculating the Jeffreys prior for the Binomial model, not just the Bernoulli model.

   2. The mean and variance of the Binomial model are as you describe.

See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution